# Need help setting up backbone.js: Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to set up a backbone driven web application but cannot get Backbone to load correctly. I get two errors when I load the required files:

-Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined                test.html: 17
-Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined    backbone.min.js: 1

I have tried multiple sources for the backbone, underscore and jquery files and am still having the same errors. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="backbone-min.js"></script>
  <script "text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
  <script "text/javascript" src="underscore-min.js"></script>
<script>
  Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        console.log("hello world");
    }
  });
  var person = new Person();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include your libraries properly to fulfill missing dependencies:

```
<script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="backbone-min.js"></script>
```

It's important to include `underscore` *before* you include `backbone` because `underscore` is a dependency of `backbone`.

> include Backbone.js and Underscore.js(a dependency of Backbone.js)

[Related introduction on backbone](http://thomasdavis.github.io/2011/02/01/backbone-introduction.html).

This is a common mistake with common libraries such as jQuery, wherea libraries like Bootstrap rely on components provided by an external provider.

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance and I can't see anything immediately wrong, although you are missing the 'type' on your second and third script tags. When you run the page in browser, are there any errors logged out to the console, can you see the libraries being loaded fine in the network viewer too? My immediate hunch would be the source paths are wrong and so the libraries aren't being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies!!! The order matters, backbone needs jQuery and underscore

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="backbone-min.js"></script>
<script>
  Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
      console.log("hello world");
    }
  });
  var person = new Person();   
</script>
</body>
```